# Manipulacion de state en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo una duda con React y el funcionamiento del state al modificarlo.

Este es mi state con los siguientes elementos:

```
this.state = {
        productos: [],
        total:0,
        subtotal:0,
        productosSeleccionado:[]
}
```

Tengo la siguiente funcion que actualiza el elemento **productosSeleccionado**

con console.log imprimo el objeto que llega y el elemento despues de modificar el **state**

```
 onclickAgregaProductos(data){
        const randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        data.unique = randomKey;
        const newObject = [data, ...this.state.productosSeleccionado];
        //console.log(data);
        this.setState({ productosSeleccionado : newObject});
        //console.log(this.state.productosSeleccionado);
}
```

cuando ejecuto la funcion por primera vez en consola no se ve reflejado esta actualizacion de state. si no hasta que mando llamar por segunda vez esta funcion y necesito calcular en este caso el total de productos.

es correcto este comportamiento en React? alguien me puede decir que hice mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En react, la función `setState` es asíncrona, se ejecutará cuando react considere, en función de la cantidad de cambios que pueda ejecutar de una vez para optimizar.  Por eso el segundo argumento de `setState` es una función tipo `callback`. Para ver reflejado el cambio una vez se ejecute la actualización del estado deberías hacer algo así:

```js
this.setState({ productosSeleccionados: newObject}, () => {
    console log(this.state.productosSeleccionados);
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, no tenia conocimiento de este segundo parametro @ilsanchez